# How to use pdfjs without webserver in offline mode

Tags: javascript, html, pdf.js

I want to run the pdfjs in offline mode without a webserver because I want to embed it in my JavaFX application and render it in WebView, so when I open the `viewer.html` file in the browser it doesn't work correctly and throws such errors as:

> Access to image at 'file:///C:/pdfjs_3/web/images/toolbarButton-viewThumbnail.svg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, isolated-app, chrome-extension, chrome, https, chrome-untrusted.

[image]

all the resource files are not accessible the same as above so,

How can I resolve such an issue and make it work without a web server?

Answer (score 0):

Inline all your resources (with [data URLs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URLs)) as [you **cannot** read other local files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local).